# Save asp.net user editable configuration settings

Tags: asp.net

I am looking to store a few random global settings in an ASP.net MVC4 application that would affect the entire application.

These setting need to be editable by the admins of the site (i made a small form)

They are things like current site wide discounts, promotion expiration dates, keys to partner services, etc.
They dont fit in a database because they are single (scalar) values that don't fit into any list (or table). They should just be in some singleton object at the application level. Yet the need to be persisted - once an admin changes the value they dont want it to be reset just because the server (or application) was reset.

I thought of storing them in the web.config file through the setting object. But I publish upgrades on a regular basis and that would overwrite the we.config on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following;

Database (prefered)

XML File

Plain text file

Any of these would give you a way of storing the information and a simple interface to read and write would allow your application access. You can then store these in either the `Application` or `Session` objects and use them accordingly.